# Trigger function to insert into different table with a join

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

Basically I've got 3 tables, table1 with line geometry, table2 with polygon geometry and table3 which is supposed to be a mashup of both

I'm trying to create a trigger that will insert into table3 whenever someone inserts into table1 with a join on table2 but my trigger isn't doing anything

table1
cid integer
type text
geom geometry linestring

table2
pid integer
name text
geom geometry polygon

table3
cid, type,pid,name

The easiest solution would be to have a view between table1 and table2 if they were small datasets, however they are both quite large so that's why I need to use table3. Problem is that my current query isnt doing anything

Current function

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_newstuff()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
      AS $function$
    DECLARE

   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table3 (cid, type,pid,name)
  select NEW.cid, new.type, pid, p.name
  from table1 c left join table2 p ON st_intersects(new.geom, p.geom)
  ;
   RETURN NEW; 

   END;
    $function$
   ;
```

The trigger query

```
   `create trigger insert_newstuff_trigger before
    insert on table1 for each row execute function insert_newstuff()
```

Problem is when inserting, nothing happens. Although it did trigger a vaccuum on table3 for some reason. How to fix the function?

Comment: It looks like your query is inserting all the rows from table1 into table3 every time someone inserts into table1.  This doesn't seem right, does it?

Comment: @Jeremy oh the goal is to just insert the inserted feature on table1. Anyway when I tested, nothing happened

Comment: I think you should try running that select statement manually using a recently inserted row.  How do you know the trigger is doing nothing?  Are there any rows in table3?